# If a2 is not empty, color empty cells in b2:af2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

Would you ple help me for below formula request in excel?

if A2 is not empty, then make empty cells RED COLOR in B2:AF2, and apply this rule to A2:AF5000

Comment: shouldn't that be applied to b2:af5000?

Answer (score 1):

Create a CFR base upon the following formula.

```
=and(len($a2), not(len(b2)))
```

[image]